# Can you push a Docker image to a private repo and only include differences from a public image?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-image

Suppose I have a private Docker repository at `myrepo.myhost.com`.

I now build an image off of a very large public Docker Registry image. Assume it's called `bandwidthguy/five-gigabyte-image:latest`.

I have a Dockerfile that does one simple thing, for example:

```
FROM bandwidthguy/five-gigabyte-image
COPY some-custom-file /etc/bigstuff
```

I build the image:

```
docker build -t myversionof-five-gigabyte-image .
```

and tag it.

```
docker tag myversionof-five-gigabyte-image:latest myrepo.myhost.com/myversions/five-gigabyte-image:latest
```

Now I push to my repo.

```
docker push myrepo.myhost.com/myversions/five-gigabyte-image
```

I noticed that when doing this, the entire large source image gets pushed to my repository.

What I'm wondering is if there is any way to somehow have Docker only push a *difference* image, and then pull the other layers from their respective sources when the image is pulled. Pushing the entire image to my private repo can have problems:

- If the private repo is hosted on my home ISP, my limited upstream can cause major lag when pulling the image while out and about.
- If the private repo is on a hosted service, it might have a disk quota and I am using 5GB of that quota needlessly.
- It takes a long time to push the image, especially if I have slow upload speed at the time.

It may just be the case that you can't put the parts on different servers, but I figured it's worth an ask to see if it can be done. It would make sense that you could store all the layers on your own host for the purposes of running an air-gapped server, but it seems a bit of an oversight that you can't pull the source images from the Registry.

Answer (score 0):

This question showcased my early misunderstanding of Docker. There is no current mechanism for storing different layers of an image on different repositories. While there's no theoretical reason this couldn't be implemented, I'm guessing it's just not worth the extra effort.

So, the answer to my question is no, you can't store only image differences in a private repo - you'll be storing all layers, including those that were pulled from the public repo, in your private repo. However, since layers are represented by their hashes, clients that have already pulled the image from the public repo won't need to re-download those layers again from the private repo. This leads to the possibility that perhaps the hashes of the very large layers could be kicked out of the private repo manually, and then users could be required to first pull the source image from public manually. (Pulling fresh from the private repo only would error out.) I haven't looked into this, but it might be a possible hacky solution.

Luckily, there aren't too many Docker images that actually need multiple gigabytes of space. Even so, layers are stored compressed and deduplicated in the registry.